# Riemann Stieltjes integral on $[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

**I am looking for a hint or feedback on what I've already done, not a full solution**
So say we have the function defined on the unit interval by:
$$
\alpha\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) =1, \alpha(t)=0, \forall t\ne \frac{1}{2}
$$
My intuitions told me that for a function $f\in C[0,1]$ 
$$
\int_{0}^{1} fd\alpha = 0
$$
My idea was: $\alpha = \alpha_{+} - \alpha_{-}$ with
$$
\alpha_{+} = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad t < \frac{1}{2} \\
            1 & \quad t \geq \frac{1}{2} 
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
$$
\alpha_{-} = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad t \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
            1 & \quad t > \frac{1}{2} 
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
So 
$$
\int_{0}^{1} fd\alpha = \int_{0}^{1} fd\alpha_{+} - \int_{0}^{1} fd\alpha_{-} = f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) - f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) =0
$$
But this result is wrong, because I know that in order for 
$$
\int_{0}^{1} fd\alpha =0
$$
to be true for $f\in C[0,1]$, $\alpha$ must be a constant map. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Why do you think that this result is wrong? Using the definition you can prove that the integral indeed equals zero.

Comment: I don't think the result is wrong, there's something in my book that says that if $\alpha$ is not a constant map then then there exists a continuous function so that this integral is not 0.

Comment: No, if $\alpha$ differs from a constant function at a finite (or even countable) number of points of $(0,1)$ then the abovementioned integral is zero for all continuous functions.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought. Thanks. Please post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $0 = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_n = 1$ be a partition and $\xi_k \in [x_k, x_{k+1}]$. If none of the points $x_i$ coincides with $\frac12$ then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\xi_k) \left( \alpha(x_{k+1}) - \alpha(x_{k}) \right) = 0.$$
Otherwise, if $x_m = \frac12$ then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\xi_k) \left( \alpha(x_{k+1}) - \alpha(x_{k}) \right) = f(\xi_{m-1}) - f(\xi_{m}) \to 0, \qquad \max_{0 \leqslant k \leqslant n-1} |x_{k+1} - x_k| \to 0.$$

In general, it can be proved that if $\alpha$ differs from a constant function at a countable number of points of $(0,1)$ then 
$$\int_0^1 fd\alpha = 0$$
for all continuous functions $f$.